# How to find the smallest node/element in a stack in O(1) time

Tags: c++, stack, min

I need to find the smallest value in a stack, but in constant time. So, because of that, I can not use a `for` loop or a `while` loop. I will provide you the code below, and I just need some hint, so I will be glad if you can help me.

Here are the header files, and `main.cpp` file.

main.cpp:

```
// Testni program za stek
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

#include "nizstektmp.h"

int Menu() { // Ispis menu opcija
    int izbor;
    cout << endl<<"---Menu----------------------" << endl<<endl;
    cout << "1. Stavi na INT stek" << endl;
    cout << "2. Skini sa INT steka" << endl;
    cout << "3. Element na vrhu INT steka" << endl;
    cout << "4. Prikazi sadrzaj INT steka" << endl;
    cout << "5. Stavi na CHAR stek" << endl;
    cout << "6. Skini sa CHAR steka" << endl;
    cout << "7. Element na vrhu CHAR steka" << endl;
    cout << "8. Prikazi sadrzaj CHAR steka" << endl;
    cout << "9. Skini vise elemenata sa INT steka" << endl;
    cout << "10. Nadji minimalan elemenat u steku O(1)" << endl;
    cout << "0. Izlaz" << endl;
    cout << endl<<"-------------Izaberite opciju>" ;
    cin >> izbor;
    if (cin)
        return izbor;
    else {
        cin.clear();
        cin.ignore(100,'\n');
        return -1;
    }
}

int main() {
    NizStek<int> intstek;
    NizStek <char> charstek;
    int izbor, x, k;
    char y;
    while (izbor=Menu()) {
        try {
            switch (izbor) {
                case 0:
                    return 0;
                case 1:
                    cout << "\nUnesite podatak:";
                    cin >> x;
                    if (!cin) throw 0;
                    intstek.StaviNaStek(x);
                    cout << "Element je umetnut" << endl;
                    break;
                case 2:
                    x=intstek.SkiniSaSteka();
                    cout << "Element " << x << " je skinut" << endl;
                    break;
                case 3:
                    cout << "\nElement na vrhu steka:" << intstek.ElementNaVrhu();
                    break;
                case 4:
                    intstek.Prikazi();
                    break;
                case 5:
                    cout << "\nUnesite podatak:";
                    cin >> y;
                    charstek.StaviNaStek(y);
                    cout << "Element je umetnut" << endl;
                    break;
                case 6:
                    y=charstek.SkiniSaSteka();
                    cout << "Element " << y << " je skinut" << endl;
                    break;
                case 7:
                    cout << "\nElement na vrhu steka:" << charstek.ElementNaVrhu();
                    break;
                case 8:
                    charstek.Prikazi();
                    break;
                case 9:
                    intstek.SkiniSaStekaVise(k);
                    break;
                case 10:
                    intstek.NadjiMinimum();
                    break;
                default:
                    cout << "Pogresan izbor" << endl;
            }
        }
        catch (const char greska[]) {
            cout << greska;
        }
        catch (...) {
            cout << "\nGreska u programu";
        }
    }
}
```

stek.h

```
// Definicija apstraktne klase “Stek”
#ifndef STEK_H
#define STEK_H

template <typename InfoTip>
class Stek {
private:
    void operator =(const Stek&); // Zaštita za dodjelu
    Stek(const Stek&); // Zaštita za konstruktor kopije
public:
    Stek() {} // Podrazumijevani konstruktor
    virtual ~Stek() {} // Bazni destruktor
    virtual void Brisi() = 0; // Reinicijalizacija steka
    virtual void StaviNaStek(const InfoTip&) = 0; // Stavljanje na stek
    virtual InfoTip SkiniSaSteka() = 0; // Skidanje sa steka
    virtual const InfoTip& ElementNaVrhu() const = 0; // Vraca vršni el.
    virtual int Duzina() const = 0; // Vraca dužinu steka
};

#endif
```

nizstek.h

```
// Definicija klase “NizStek”
#ifndef NIZSTEK_H
#define NIZSTEK_H

#include "stek.h"

template <typename InfoTip>
class NizStek : public Stek<InfoTip> {
private:
    InfoTip *Elementi; // Niz koji sadrži elemente steka
    int kapacitet; // Kapacitet steka
    int vrh; // Vrh steka
public:
    NizStek(int kapacitet = 10) : kapacitet(kapacitet), // Konstruktor
        vrh(-1), Elementi(new InfoTip[kapacitet]) {}
    ~NizStek() {delete [] Elementi; } // Destruktor
    void Brisi() { vrh = -1; } // Brisanje
    void StaviNaStek (const InfoTip &x); // Stavljanje na stek
    InfoTip SkiniSaSteka(); // Skidanje sa steka
    const InfoTip& ElementNaVrhu() const; // Vraca vršni element
    bool JeLiPrazan() const { return vrh == -1; } // Je li stek prazan?
    bool JeLiPun() const { return vrh == kapacitet - 1; } // Je li stek pun?
    int Duzina() const { return vrh + 1; } // Vraca dužinu steka
    void Prikazi() const; // Ispis sadržaja steka
    InfoTip SkiniSaStekaVise(int k);
    InfoTip NadjiMinimum();
};

#endif
```

nizstektmp.h

```
// Definicija metoda klase “NizStek”
#ifndef NIZSTEKTMP_H
#define NIZSTEKTMP_H

#include "nizstek.h"

template <typename InfoTip> // Stavljanje na stek
void NizStek<InfoTip>::StaviNaStek(const InfoTip &x) {
    if (JeLiPun())
        throw "\nStek je pun!\n";
    Elementi[++vrh] = x;
}

template <typename InfoTip> // Skidanje sa steka
InfoTip NizStek<InfoTip>::SkiniSaSteka() {
    if (JeLiPrazan())
        throw "\nStek prazan!\n";
    return Elementi[vrh--];
}

template <typename InfoTip> // Vraca vršni element
const InfoTip& NizStek<InfoTip>::ElementNaVrhu() const {
    if (JeLiPrazan())
        throw "\nStek prazan!\n";
    return Elementi[vrh];
}

template <typename InfoTip> // Ispis sadržaja steka
void NizStek<InfoTip>::Prikazi() const {
    cout << endl << "Sadrzaj steka:" << endl << endl;
    for(int i = vrh; i >= 0; i--)
        cout << i << ":" << Elementi[i] << endl;
}

template <typename InfoTip>
InfoTip NizStek<InfoTip>::SkiniSaStekaVise(int k) {
    if(JeLiPrazan())
        throw "\nStek prazan!\n";
    cout << "Koliko elemenata zelite skinuti sa steka: ";
    cin >> k;
    vrh -= k;
    return Elementi[vrh];
}

template <typename InfoTip>
InfoTip NizStek<InfoTip>::NadjiMinimum() {
    InfoTip *PomocniStek = new InfoTip[kapacitet];
    int noviVrh = 0;
    PomocniStek[noviVrh++] = vrh;
    if(noviVrh >= 0 && Elementi[vrh] < PomocniStek[noviVrh]) {
        PomocniStek[noviVrh++] = vrh;
    } else if (noviVrh == -1) {
        PomocniStek[noviVrh++] = vrh;
    }
    cout << "Najmanji elemenat u stacku je: " << noviVrh << endl;
}

#endif
```

The function I am using to get the minimum element is called `NadjiMinimum()`. I have the idea of making a new stack and copying only the elements that are lower then the rest of the elements in that stack, so that I need to only return the top element in the stack.

Am I making a mistake, or is something like that possible?

Comment: you can only "find" the minimum element in constant time when you already know what is the smallest element. For example if you have a sorted container then you know that the first element is the smallest. Otherwise it is unclear why you think there exists a `O(1)` algorithm

Comment: So you are saying it is impossible to do this in O(1)?

Comment: I'd be glad to be proven wrong, but I have no clue how that should be possible

Comment: Thank you for the responding!

Comment: O(1) means you have to visit one entry in order to get the item you seek. The only way you can do this task in O(1) is with a container that allows random access when you already know where the item is. Stacks don't do random access, you can only access the item on top, so unless the item is on top of the stack, you have to do too much work to qualify for O(1)

Comment: consider you are given a stack of paper and you are supposed to find the piece of paper that has the smallest number written on it. You can look at each piece, then you know which has the smallest number. But if you are only allowed to pick a single piece of paper it is difficult to pick the right one

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 thank you now I get it!

Comment: @user4581301 I get it, thank you for helping me!

Comment: There are [various bookkeeping tricks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/design-a-stack-that-supports-getmin-in-o1-time-and-o1-extra-space/) or [use of multiple stacks](https://www.techiedelight.com/design-stack-which-returns-minimum-element-constant-time/) that allow this to be achieved if your problem allows you to take more space to hold extra stacks and/or entries as part of your design.

Comment: @user4581301 That’s not what O(1) means. Visiting 1000 elements is still O(1). The only thing that matters for O(1) is that the number of elements you inspect mustn’t depend on the size of the stack; it must be (bounded) constant.

Comment: Just as a side note: Your code would be easier for other people to understand if you provided a [mre] in English language, i.e. if all the variables names, output and comments were in English.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel Yeah I am sorry for that. I hope you do not mind it!